# Setup multiple facebook LoginButton in multiple activity

Tags: android, facebook

I'm dealing with this strange behavior where the same code, used in 2 different activities, is producing a different output.

The code is the standard facebook sdk login iteration, so:

```
private CallbackManager fbCallbackManager;
private LoginButton signFacebookButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
    fbCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.sign);
    signFacebookButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_fb_button);
    signFacebookButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
    signFacebookButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    signFacebookButton.registerCallback(fbCallbackManager, fbCallback);

}

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> fbCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.d("Facebook Callback", "success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("Facebook Callback", "cancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.d("Facebook Callback", "error");
    }
};
```

This same exact code used in two different activities is behaving differently.

In the activity where is it first called, it works properly, but if I skip the first activity (so I don't click the login button), but then click a new login button in a second activity, the code is simply not working. It show the facebook progress bar for a couple of seconds, then nothing happen (nor any of the log is printed in the console). Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After half a day wasted behind this, I noticed that I was missing the actual fbcallbackManager call in `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    this.fbCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```